# Remove "home title" from front page while copy and paste site link to social media

Tags: wordpress, linkedin-api, share

I created a Wordpress site using Divi Builder

Whenever I share link to Linkedin

[image]

I need to remove or edit "Home" title while sharing on LinkedIn as changing front page title didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

That is because of your page name. LinkedIn is taking page name as Title on the post. You can change the page name as if you want other title at the post. You can keep a title matching name any thing by changing the page name.

Go to pages inside admin of wordpress site than edit home page  title. Automatically the change will be visible on linkedin post as you put url there.

Comment: I had Already Changed Page Name Home to Ceorra, Still Didn't Worked as It displays all other pages correctly the issue is regarding only for home page

Answer (score 1):

For this you have to make sure your code complies with Open Graph Protocol(OGP). 
And for that you'll have to add some of the following meta tags:

```
<meta property='og:title' content='Title of the article"/>
<meta property='og:image' content='//media.example.com/ 1234567.jpg"/>
<meta property='og:description' content='Description that will show in the preview"/>
<meta property='og:url' content='//www.example.com/URL of the article" />
```

And whatever value you add in `meta property='og:title'`, will appear as the title on linkedin.

More info available here: https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en